# Facebook Open Graph id return value

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

My setup: Facebook C# sdk, MVC 2, Facebook Canvas Application, Windows Azure Hosting

I've setup an Object and Action using the new Open Graph tools for my Facebook Application.  And can successfully POST/Publish to the action using:

[image]

In the dynamic result parameter I get this returned:

[id, 204223079646743],

How does this id field relate in the context of the Open Graph?  What can I do with it? Can I receive more than one of these id fields from Facebook ?  Should I cater for that?

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know the api call to do it, I believe the id returned can be used in graph calls to get more information (likes, comments, etc).  Try putting the id into Facebook's graph explorer and see what you can get from it.